# windows service not firing in c#

Tags: c#, windows-services

i have been running a windows service for over a year that copies files from one folder to another.it writes a time to a text file and after every time interval it checks the time that was written in the text file to the file that has to be copied,if the file to be copied is greater than the time written in the text file then it will be copied. Its now stopped working i tried deleting the service and reinstalling from visual studio command prompt but it doesn't work.

```
 public partial class FileService : ServiceBase
{
    Timer aTimer = new Timer();
    public FileService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        aTimer.Interval = 60000;
        aTimer.Start();
    }
    private void CopyFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            string ReadTextFile=File.ReadAllText(@"\\10.0.0.0\c$\Database\tempFolder\date.txt");
            DateTime TimeInTextFile = Convert.ToDateTime(ReadTextFile);

            if (File.GetLastWriteTime(@"\\10.19.0.1\folder\file.dbf") > TimeInTextFile)
            {
                File.Copy(@"\\10.19.0.1\folder\file.dbf", @"\\10.0.0.0\c$\Database\tempFolder" + "\\_file.dbf", true);                  
                StreamWriter WriterTotxt = new StreamWriter(@"\\10.0.0.0\c$\Database\tempFolder\date.txt, false);
                DateTime LastVipAccess = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"\\10.19.0.1\folder\file.dbf");
                WriterTotxt.Write(LastVipAccess);
                WriterTotxt.Flush();
                WriterTotxt.Close();
                RenameAndMoveFiles();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                string[] RenamedDbfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\10.0.0.0\c$\Database\", "*.dbf__");
                foreach (string f in RenamedDbfFiles)
                {
                    File.Delete(f);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void RenameAndMoveFiles()
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"\\10.0.0.0\c$\Database\" + "file.dbf"))
        {

            File.Move(@"\\10.0.0.0\c$\Database\ + "file.dbf", @"\\10.0.0.0\c$\Database\" + "file.dbf__");
        }
        else if (!File.Exists(@"\\10.0.0.0\c$\Database\" + "*.dbf"))
        {
            File.Move(@"\\10.0.0.0\c$\Database\tempFolder\" + "_file.dbf", @"\\10.0.0.0\c$\Database\" + "file.dbf");
        }
    }
    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CopyFiles();
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what happens when you try to start the service ?

Comment: Is the service running? Check it in services.msc. Enable logging.

Comment: Do you have any related entry in the Windows Event Viewer? Could you introduce a logging library to check where the the service stops?

Comment: And what happens when you attach a debugger and debug the service?

Comment: I'd reckon something might have changed with permissions, so when you try to find all files it just returns an empty list.

Comment: the service is running,it just doesnt do anything anymore.it doesnt write the time to the text file or copy anything

Comment: i checked permissions and assigned the folder to "Everyone" just for testing purposes but still nothing happends

Comment: Take out that `try`/`catch` block - services don't have a `Console` attached and it's actively harming your attempt to diagnose the issue by hiding whatever exceptions are occurring.

Comment: when i run it as a console application it works fine but as a services it doesnt,i took out the try and catch

Comment: stupid question.....you haven't just run out of disk space, this sound like a classic scenario for that